# mdadm checking RAID 5 array after each restart

Tags: server, hard-drive, mdadm, raid5

system info:
Ubuntu 20.04
Software raid 5 (added 3rd HDD and converted from raid 1).
FS is Ext4 over LUKS.

I saw a system slowdown after a restart, so I checked the array status via proc/mdstat, and it show following:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid5 sdb[2] sdc[0] sdd[1]
      7813772928 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      [==>..................]  check = 14.3% (558996536/3906886464) finish=322.9min speed=172777K/sec
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
unused devices: <none>
```

It is re-checking, but I don't know why. There is no cron job setup. Here is the log entry, which occurs after each restart, after system has been converted to RAID5, but I am not sure, has it been re-checking every time or not:

```
Jan  3 14:34:47 <sysname> kernel: [    3.473942] md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 2
Jan  3 14:34:47 <sysname> kernel: [    3.475170] md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 0
Jan  3 14:34:47 <sysname> kernel: [    3.476402] md/raid:md0: device sdd operational as raid disk 1
Jan  3 14:34:47 <sysname> kernel: [    3.478290] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 3 out of 3 devices, algorithm 2
Jan  3 14:34:47 <sysname> kernel: [    3.520677] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 8001303478272
```

**mdadm --detail /dev/md0**

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Nov 25 23:06:18 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 7813772928 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906886464 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent
     Intent Bitmap : Internal
       Update Time : Sun Jan  3 16:17:28 2021
    State : clean, checking
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0
            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K
Consistency Policy : bitmap
      Check Status : 16% complete
              Name : ubuntu-server:0
              UUID : <UUID>
            Events : 67928
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
       1       8       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
       2       8       16        2      active sync   /dev/sdb
```

Is this a normal behavior or not?

Appreciate any input

Comment: This older Ubuntu forum entry might be of help to you. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1800123 by the way it took less then a min to find info on your question with a google search.

Comment: @David thank you for your input and for teaching me how to google! appreciate it. I have found tons of similar topics, but in my case, raid was not failing or stopping, just checking. In this case for example, first place to look are the cron jobs, since debian/ubuntu might be doing scheduled checks. Not in my case. After this check I have restarted the server and I see no issues anymore (checks). That's why I asked, is it normal on not. Thanks anyways, that old info can be helpful as well, some day

Comment: In any case, you should be aware that this is a script which is triggered on the first Sunday of each month, to check if the RAID array is healthy. If the array is huge and the check requires many hours to finish, it will run for a couple of hours per day until the entire array has been checked. It shouldn't be disabled unless you make sure that you're periodically checking through other means.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/625724/100853 this shows you how to pause the RAID check/rebuild as well as how to throttle the bandwidth consumed for the check/rebuild, so that working with the machine becomes feasible.

Comment: Also, to answer the question: Yes, it is normal that the check continues if the machine got shut down while it was still checking. This is not a problem. Maybe just throttling the max_speed as in the comment above might be what you want. At least that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 18/06/2021

for svc in mdcheck_start.timer mdcheck_continue.timer; do sudo systemctl stop ${svc}; sudo systemctl disable ${svc}; done

Taken from:
https://a20.net/bert/2020/11/02/disable-periodic-raid-check-on-ubuntu-20-04-systemd/

UPDATE 04/05/2021 begin.
My previous answer seems to be not helpful.
The check occurred again despite the change in `/etc/default/mdadm`.

I've found something else to investigate.
`mdcheck_start.service`
`mdcheck_start.timer`
`mdcheck_continue.service`
`mdcheck_continue.timer`
`/etc/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service.wants/mdcheck_start.timer`
`/etc/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service.wants/mdcheck_continue.timer`
`/etc/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service.wants/mdmonitor-oneshot.timer`

```
systemctl status mdcheck_start.service
● mdcheck_start.service - MD array scrubbing
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● mdcheck_start.timer
```

```
systemctl status mdcheck_start.timer
● mdcheck_start.timer - MD array scrubbing
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2021-05-02 19:40:50 CEST; 1 day 14h ago
    Trigger: Sun 2021-06-06 22:36:42 CEST; 1 months 3 days left
   Triggers: ● mdcheck_start.service

May 02 19:40:50 xxx systemd[1]: Started MD array scrubbing.
```

```
systemctl status mdcheck_continue.service
● mdcheck_continue.service - MD array scrubbing - continuation
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● mdcheck_continue.timer
  Condition: start condition failed at Tue 2021-05-04 06:38:39 CEST; 3h 26min ago
             └─ ConditionPathExistsGlob=/var/lib/mdcheck/MD_UUID_* was not met
```

```
systemctl status mdcheck_continue.timer
● mdcheck_continue.timer - MD array scrubbing - continuation
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2021-05-02 19:40:50 CEST; 1 day 14h ago
    Trigger: Wed 2021-05-05 00:35:53 CEST; 14h left
   Triggers: ● mdcheck_continue.service

May 02 19:40:50 xxx systemd[1]: Started MD array scrubbing - continuation.
```

```
sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service.wants/mdcheck_start.timer
#  This file is part of mdadm.
#
#  mdadm is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=MD array scrubbing

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-1..7 1:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=24h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=mdmonitor.service
Also=mdcheck_continue.timer
```

```
sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service.wants/mdcheck_continue.timer 
#  This file is part of mdadm.
#
#  mdadm is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=MD array scrubbing - continuation

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
RandomizedDelaySec=12h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=mdmonitor.service
```

```
sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service.wants/mdmonitor-oneshot.timer 
#  This file is part of mdadm.
#
#  mdadm is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Reminder for degraded MD arrays

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
RandomizedDelaySec=24h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy= mdmonitor.service
```

UPDATE 04/05/2021 end.

---

Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdadm`.

Please note that I am not sure if the above tip would help.
I have the same problem with my raid5 on 20.04.

First I've tried editing the `/etc/default/mdadm` manually and changed `AUTOCHECK=true` into `AUTOCHECK=false`.
It did not help.

Today I've used `dpkg-reconfigure mdadm`.
Now the `/etc/default/mdadm` file looks the same (`AUTOCHECK=false`) but as a part of `dpkg-reconfigure mdadm` there was also an `update-initramfs` call. I hope it will help.

`... update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) ...`

The extended log:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdadm
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[897059]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 655310: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[897059]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 655310: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-71-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-70-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-70-generic
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[897059]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 655841: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[897059]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 655841: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
done
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
```

The full `/etc/default/mdadm` file:

```
cat /etc/default/mdadm 
# mdadm Debian configuration
#
# You can run 'dpkg-reconfigure mdadm' to modify the values in this file, if
# you want. You can also change the values here and changes will be preserved.
# Do note that only the values are preserved; the rest of the file is
# rewritten.
#

# AUTOCHECK:
#   should mdadm run periodic redundancy checks over your arrays? See
#   /etc/cron.d/mdadm.
AUTOCHECK=false

# AUTOSCAN:
#   should mdadm check once a day for degraded arrays? See
#   /etc/cron.daily/mdadm.
AUTOSCAN=true

# START_DAEMON:
#   should mdadm start the MD monitoring daemon during boot?
START_DAEMON=true

# DAEMON_OPTIONS:
#   additional options to pass to the daemon.
DAEMON_OPTIONS="--syslog"

# VERBOSE:
#   if this variable is set to true, mdadm will be a little more verbose e.g.
#   when creating the initramfs.
VERBOSE=false
```

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit to let the OP know *why* reconfiguring `mdadm` will resolve the issue? This could also help others in the future who experience the same issue 

Comment: @matigo I've added extended info. Tnx for pinging me.

Comment: Also related files: `/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.service` and `/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.service`. To edit them, make copies of them into `/etc/systemd/system/` and edit those copies.